# Vector bundle with flat connection over simply connected manifold is trivial

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

I am trying to finish a proof of the statement in the title. Let $M$ be a simply connected smooth manifold and $E \twoheadrightarrow M$ be a vector bundle with a flat connection. Since the bundle is flat we can choose a local trivialization at every point such that the connection is trivial in all trivializations (with null 1-form matrix). Because of this, and because of the transition formula between the connection matrices of 1-forms, the transition functions between such trivializations are constant. I would like to use this fact, together with the simple connectedness of $M$ to either reduce the structure group to the trivial group or to build a basis of global sections, but I am a bit rusty with these proofs and I cannot come up with an intelligent idea to do this. Any hint?

Comment: So parallel translation of a section around any loop returns you to the same value you started with. This means that you get a well-defined parallel translation to all points of the manifold. Do this with a frame at the initial point and you have a basis of global sections.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping it could be done without any parallel transport or holonomy as it is an exercise in some notes that do not mention these topics at all! Do you by chance know of a modern reference where to read about holonomy for generic vector bundles? I cannot find it on any book!

Comment: @NicolòCavalleri you may refer to the excellent expository paper called Surface Group Representations and Higgs Bundles by Peter Gothen.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.0568